# Update Extended Properties of a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database, updates

Dummy in SQL here needing to update an extended property of a stored procedure. Can only find info on updating table contents, not properties.

Needing to send a query to a database from a C# function.

It would read something like;

```
string query = "Update StoredProcedureName SET caption = 'newValue' WHERE caption = 'oldValue' "
```

Where caption is the name of an extended property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can find info about how to update an extended property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186885.aspx

example :

```
string query = "EXEC sp_updateextendedproperty  ";
query += "     @name = N'Caption'  ";
query += "     ,@value = 'newValue.'   "; 
query += "     ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = dbo    ";
query += "     ,@level1type = N'Procedure',  @level1name = STOREDPROCNAME    ";
query += "     ,@level2type = N'Property', @level2name = Caption;    ";
```

than send your query to your database as you did before

Comment: Looks on point. Does that imply something like. 
`UPDATE Database.StoredProcedure 
EXEC sp_updateextendedproperty 
@name = N'Caption' 
,@value = 'newValue.' 
GO `

?

Comment: @beatsandbosons I have edited my answer, hope it is more clear now

Comment: Have a look at the link in my answer, it will explain it all in more detail

Comment: I see. So, in theory running
`EXEC sp_updateextendedproperty 
    @name = N'Description'
    ,@value = 'Test success.'
    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = dbo
    ,@level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = T1
    ,@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = id;`
in the stored procedure itself should change the extended property "Description" value to "Test successful"?

Doesn't seem to work as it is. May need to educate myself a little more. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Edited my answer again, but you should take a look at the link. You need to change Level1type to N'Procedure', @Level1name = procname. Have not tested it but this and the link should get you in the right direction